# Htaccess: redirect folder to page.php (clean URL)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I've been reading a lot of similar posts about this but I cannot get it to work.

What I want:

domain.com/birthday/page1.php to be accessible by just using domain.com/birthday

Do I place the .htaccess in the website root or in the folder?

(unfortunately the name page1.php cannot be modified)

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried so far ?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

Go to directory /birthday and inside its .htaccess put the following code :

```
DirectoryIndex page1.php
```

Comment: Glad to help , if you satisfied please accept the answer